# New wheel bearing is stiff

Tags: wheel-bearing

The garage fitted a new SKF drum bearing and the top cylinder is so stiff I can't turn it without using both hands, while the lower cylinder spins freely using one finger.
[image]

it's a 2001 Ford Focus mk1
Did the garage do a bad job? It was more than twice the price of an entire new Bosch drum and cylinder, should I take it to other garages to get a note from them that it's a bad fitting?

Comment: What vehicle does this belong to? (year/make/model/engine)

Comment: I've noticed in the past that new wheel bearings can be stiff, but they usually ease up after a few miles of driving.  But it's also possible that the bearing was damaged or something during installation.   Did you drive it?  If it's really bad, you should notice is getting very HOT very quickly.

Comment: Cheers jwh20 that's encouraging. I haven't driven it.

Answer (score 0):

can be normal for some wheel bearings to be stiff and hard to turn right after installation. That's because some manufacturers pre-fill the hub units and sealed bearings with high quality bearing grease.

Manufacturers make sure to pre-fill these units with grease that is:

High load.
High temperature.
High viscosity